# Rails - creating a notification pop-up system similar to that of Skype

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make it a notification. What I have in mind right now is a notification system similar to that of Skype.if any person can be a create a new event in application that time show notification in the header.

Any help/advice/answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please review the [how to ask a question page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is too opinion based and isn't the type of question meant to be asked on SO.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a model for your notifications and subscribe all your users to a websocket connection. When they visit the site any type of notification gets broadcasted to all users that are connected to the websocket at that moment. If you like, you can send also an email after the notification was created.

Depending on the version of Rails you are using you will have to use either Faye websockets (https://faye.jcoglan.com/) for 4.X or use ActionCable (websocket) in Rails 5 (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html).

Read as much as you can about how to use websockets and how the connection works. It can be a bit tricky to understand.

If you are willing to use a service, you can use Pusher. They have a free tier and then it starts at around $49 a month depending on the number of connections and amount of messages (notifications) you want to broadcast. (https://pusher.com/)